# CSS animation with JQuery addClass. Run only once using true or false

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a CSS animation that I want to run when the page is in view on the browser. I am doing this using a true or false function to get the position (called "posish"). I can run it once when the page comes into view, or when posish is true (13900), but I also want to run it again once when posish becomes false.

My problem is, if I set it up so true & false both run the animation, the animation runs continuously as you scroll, whereas I only want it to run once for each instance until the instance changes to the opposite. Also, I have two classes running the same animation, so I can add and remove. I hope this makes sense! Here is my code:

```
if (posish(13900)) {    
    $('.shadow').removeClass('shrink-2');   
    $('.shadow').addClass('shrink-1');
} else {
    $('.shadow').removeClass('shrink-1');
    $('.shadow').addClass('shrink-2');  
}
```

Here is the code for the posish function

```
function posish(pos) {
    pos-=19;
    if (scrolled-viewport/4 < pos) {
        return false;
    } else if (scrolled > pos+viewport/2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return (scrolled-viewport/4-pos)/(viewport/4);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the value of `viewport`?

Comment: `viewport = $(window).height();

The posish function provides a true or false based on whether you are above the number 13900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a Fiddle I made to demo some code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3XbTG/

If you run it and look at the console, you'll see that it successfully tests the two posish values.

I think what you want to do is see if the "pos" is greater than 1/4 of the total viewport height (the height + the scroll position - 19)

The first problem is you want to get the values of `viewport` and `scrolled` each time you run the function.

The second problem is you should only run a single test, and return the value from that.  Your function was returning booleans or numbers, which is confusing.

```
function posish(pos) {
    var viewport = $(window).height();
    var scrolled = $('body').scrollTop();
    var totalHeight = scrolled + viewport - 19;
    return (totalHeight / 4 < pos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Steven. I'm not able to try that out today, will try it out early next week and let you know how I go. Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Steve. I managed to try your new function out, it seemed to stop the rest of the site working. It's probably far too big a can of worms to open, so I've left it for now! Thanks for your help though, all the best.